# XML fragment validation during unmarshalling

Tags: xml, jaxb, fragment, unmarshalling

We have to unmarshalling very huge xml files structured like these.

```
<document1 xlsns="doc1">  
   <presentation> ... </presentation>
   <presentation> ... </presentation>
    . . . 
   <image> ... </image>
   <image> ... </image>
</document1>

<document2 xlsns="doc2">  
   <presentation> ... </presentation>
    . . . 
   <image> ... </image>
</document2>
```

JAXB generated classes for presentation and image element are unique (are based on unique xsd). Only classes document1,2..n are marked as XlmRootElement.

We are using a staxEventReader for read fragments (presentation & image) and jaxb for unmarshalling it like so

```
jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(eventReader, Presentation.class); 
jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(eventReader, Image.class);
```

Ok, it works.

But now we have to validate fragments (filtering bad fragments). Adding schemas and validationHandler we get

> cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Presentation|Image'

We can't modify xsd files.

Can we validate fragment in our context? Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Basically, Schema validation only works on whole documents, not fragments. So you might want to use JAXB to marshal your fragment into a document and then validate that.

Comment: Sure I known, but we are using staxEventReader (inside Spring Batch job): how can we recover xml fragment source from reader without altering the main stream (ithat is without consume events)?